# Pandoc Conversion and \hypertarget

Tags: pandoc, hypertarget

I converted a long text from Markdown to LaTeX and am trying to clean it up. I found this code and don't know what it does:

Specifically:

\hypertarget

\texorpdfstring

\label

I have no idea what the function of these three is.

```
\hypertarget{chapter-two-maintenance-of-authorization}{%
\subsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\textbf{Chapter Two -- Maintenance of
Authorization}}{Chapter Two -- Maintenance of Authorization}}\label{chapter-two-    maintenance-of-authorization}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\hypertarget` and `\texorpdfstring` are defined by the hyperref package. See [its documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf). The first sets something as a target for links created by the `\hyperlink` command. This allows for links in documents with arbitrary text.

The `\texorpdfstring` allows you to use different content in the actual document as opposed to the pdf bookmarks, where, e.g., LaTeX commands are not appropriate. (The first argument is used in the body of the document; the second in the bookmarks/pdf table of contents.) In this particular example, the two arguments are the same, so it wasn't necessary to use it, but pandoc probably uses that construct by default when doing sectioning to strip out stuff that doesn't belong in the pdf bookmarks (pdf table of contents).

`\label` is a LaTeX built in command for labeling a numbered object allowing to refer back to it later with command such as `\ref`. In this case, this would allow us to refer back to the subsubsection and print its number, whatever it is. If hyperref is loaded, `\ref` and similar commands will also be made into hyperlinks.

Comment: Since the text produced will be a printed pdf, it doesn't seem that these packages or commands are necessary. Is there a simple way to strip them out? (Commenting out the packages is easy enough, but there are more than a thousand instances of the hyper target command...)

Comment: `\label` might actually be necessary for a printed PDF if there are crossreferences. For the others, do you want to make them do nothing, or do you want them gone from the code? The first is easy. You could just use `\renewcommand`. For the second, do you want to modify how pandoc works so they are never created? (E.g., if need to use this process routinely?) Or is this a one-time thing you want to clean up in this specific document? For the latter, if you have a good text editor, you can probably do it with regex find and replaces.

Comment: The odd thing is that the sections, subsections, etc. are all un-numbered without the use of the \section* syntax. Maybe there's a global switch in the preamble that I'm not recognizing, but I didn't think this was possible.

Comment: Usually `\section*{...}` gives you an unnumbered section and `\section{...}` without the star would give you a numbered one, but it depends also on the `secnumdepth` counter, which might be set to something nonstandard, and possibly the documentclass. The `--number-sections` (`-N`) and `--top-level-division` flags in pandoc would affect this in certain ways. Hard to say what's going on in your document without seeing the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to leave them in for the time being and then we'll see if I can generate an accurate ToC and running headers. In the meanwhile, 30,000 lines to go...